# High RAM usage/software shutdown at 75%?

Tags: windows, windows-8, memory, windows-10, memory-management

How come when my memory is at around 75% I get popups saying that my programs should be shut down, and sometimes they even fail to start when it's at around 80% (even though they would be using 2-5% of memory, which means I'd still be left with at least 15% of free memory)?

I find that quite annoying, and in my mind - that makes 20-25% of my RAM useless.

In addition to wanting to know why this is how it is, I also want to know if there's a way of "fixing" this.

Using Windows 10 (same thing was happening in Win8) and have 16GB of memory.

Comment: post pictures of RAMMap, Taskmgr->Perf->Memory and ResMon->Memory

Comment: Yea, here's a few: http://postimg.org/gallery/1wwbc9ai2/

Comment: post the entire Window and not that small part. But you have a lot of "modified" memory. Do you use a broadcom Wifi adapter?

Comment: The entire window would contain the software that I use. Like Virtualbox, Chrome, Firefox, etc., etc.. It is not something I want to share publicly, nor is it something that has any problematic software - all the software that I use is widely used (and not sketchy) and up-to-date. I do not use any wifi adapters, I use an Ethernet cable + integrated port.

Comment: if you don't share this information we must close the question as "too broad" to be helped.

Comment: I wouldn't stop using any program that I am using right now anyway, and if there was a problem with any of them specifically, I'm quite sure someone would have reported it already. That said, it's a problem with Windows itself, or rather the fact that it throws the error when I still have plenty of free RAM.

Comment: No, Windows has no issues, it comes from 3rd party drivers and software. I've voted now to close the question. We can't solve it without the information that you don't want to provide.

Comment: The information is simply my software using up memory. I will not stop using any of it, no matter what. And still - as far as I know, Windows manages the memory, which means that if it says I've 20% free memory, it's not low and Windows should not close applications nor throw errors.

Comment: I gave it up. I already voted to close it. Bye.